# Pandas plot sum of occurrence of string

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hi hoping someone can help. I have a data frame where one of the columns contains a list of names. These names are repeated in some circumstances but not all. I am trying to plot a graph where the x-axis contains the name and then the y-axis contains the number of times that name appears in the column.

I have used the following to count the number of time each name appears.

```
df.groupby('name').name.count()
```

Then tried to use the following to plot the graph. However, I get a key error messasge.

```
df.plot.bar(x='name', y=df.groupby('name').name.count())
```

Anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need plot `Series` returned from `count` function by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df.groupby('name').name.count().plot.bar()
```

Or use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['name'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks. Been driving me mad all day.